# Visual Studio Code , Python and Output problem of defined Function

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code . I am working on python using the editor Visual Studio Code. I have installed certain packages to run python on VS code like I have installed python 3.9.6 version and also added it to the PATH.

I am working on defining a function on python..there, I am getting some problem...The Code is like below :

```
def greeting(name):
    print("Welcome, " + name )
```

After I have tried to run code it's only showing something like that:

```
PS D:\PYTHON CODES> python -u "d:\PYTHON CODES\2_def_function.py"
PS D:\PYTHON CODES>
```

How do I get VSCode to display my program's output ?

Comment: Did you call the function?

Comment: Hi, if you just declare a function it won't do anything if you do not call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all make sure you are using the correct python interpreter (bottom left corner), then make sure you have the extension code runner installed.

then run your code:

```
def greeting(name):
    print("Welcome, " + name )

greeting("Some_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may not have called the function. Try something like this. It's your same function but just calling it with your name afterward will allow the print statement that you wrote to be reachable.

```
def greeting(name):
    print("Welcome, " + name )


greeting("Pruthviraj Anuse")
```

If that's not the issue try just running

```
python "d:\PYTHON CODES\2_def_function.py"
```